# What happens if I forget to mark the Spring SessionStatus as "Complete"?

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, annotations

In Spring MVC, suppose I define a SessionAttribute, using the @SessionAttribute tag like so:

```
@SessionAttributes(value = "myModel")
public class MyController{
   ...
}
```

Suppose that I forget to call status.setComplete() on the SessionStatus like so:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doSomething(@ModelAttribute("myModel") MyModel model, SessionStatus status){
   ...
   //status.setComplete(); <-- Never gets called
}
```

Will the model stay in the session forever? Will it ever get cleaned out, or will the session keep growing larger and larger as the user navigates the site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT #2: Note that this answer is no longer correct. See [@doanduyhai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9331400/294657) below.

EDIT: Please note that this is for Spring 2.5 and may, but does not necessarily ensure that the same is for Spring 3.x. Double check the docs!

This is along the lines of what @Gandalf said.

Form controllers model a form request lifespan, from initial viewing of the form through form submission. After the form is submitted, the form controller's job is done, and it will remove the command object from the session.

So, to keep the command object in the session between form workflows you will need to manage the session manually.  After a clean POST, the object is removed from session.

In short, I believe the setComplete() method is just good practice but is not necessarily required.

**EDIT**:  I just looked in my Spring book to confirm this.  I'll quote it:

> When @SessionAttribute is not used, a
>   new command object will be created on
>   each request, even when rendering the
>   form again due to binding errors.  If
>   this annotation is enabled, the
>   command object will be stored in the
>   session for subsequent uses, **until
>   the form completes successfully.  Then
>   this command object will be cleared
>   from the session.**  This is usually
>   used when the command object is a
>   persistent object that needs to be
>   identical across different requests
>   for tracking changes.

Essentially that's what I was saying above.  It stores it in the session until you either A) call setComplete() or B) the controller successfully completes a POST.

Comment: Excellent answer. I assume that a "successful form completion" is defined as being when errors.hasErrors() == false?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. Looking at Spring's documentation for @SessionAttributes (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) it says: Those attributes will be removed once the handler indicates completion of its conversational session. I'm not quite sure what that means.

Comment: Session attribute is not removed until you call setComplete explicitly. E.g. after successful post I redirect to edit again and still can see values from session although I didn't save them in the database. This is how at least latest Spring 3.0.x behaves. So there still no answer to the question.

Comment: @OMax I believe this was changed in 3.0 specifically because the behavior was a bit confusing, which is what lead to this question.  Therefore this answer should still hold true for 2.5.

Comment: Well, then mentioning 2.5 version in the answer could be helpful, because in comments you reference spring 3.0 doc.

Answer (score 22):

There is a big debate on whether the session attributes are cleared after controller exit.

To clarify once and for all, we can look at the **Spring MVC 3.1.0 RELEASE** source code.

The interface ***org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionAttributeStore*** exposes the following methods:

```
void storeAttribute(WebRequest request, String attributeName, Object attributeValue);

Object retrieveAttribute(WebRequest request, String attributeName);

void cleanupAttribute(WebRequest request, String attributeName);
```

The default implementation is ***org.springframework.web.bind.support.DefaultSessionAttributeStore***

By doing a "*Open Call Hierarchy*" on *cleanupAttribute()* in Eclipse, we can see that the method is called by 2 different flows:

1) ***org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelFactory***

```
public void updateModel(NativeWebRequest request, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer) throws Exception {

        if (mavContainer.getSessionStatus().isComplete()){
            this.sessionAttributesHandler.cleanupAttributes(request);
        }
        else {
            this.sessionAttributesHandler.storeAttributes(request, mavContainer.getModel());
        }

        if (!mavContainer.isRequestHandled()) {
            updateBindingResult(request, mavContainer.getModel());
        } 
    }
```

2) ***org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker***

```
public final void updateModelAttributes(Object handler, Map<String, Object> mavModel,
            ExtendedModelMap implicitModel, NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {

        if (this.methodResolver.hasSessionAttributes() && this.sessionStatus.isComplete()) {
            for (String attrName : this.methodResolver.getActualSessionAttributeNames()) {
                this.sessionAttributeStore.cleanupAttribute(webRequest, attrName);
            }
        }
...
}
```

It is clear that in both cases, the session attribute is removed only when *this.sessionStatus.isComplete()* is called.

I dug into the code of ***DefaultSessionAttributeStore***. Under the hood, it gets the real **HTTP Session** object to store attributes, so they can potentially be accessed by other controllers in the same session.

**So no, the session attributes are not removed after a clean POST.**

Answer (score 1):

Is there some reason why you would want to do that?

from this thread : [@SessionAttribute Problem](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=49396)

> The @SessionAttributes works in the same way as the sessionForm of the SimpleFormController. It puts the command (or for the @SessionAttributes any object) in the session for the duration between the first and the last request (most of the time the initial GET and the final POST). After that the stuff is removed.

Comment: "After that the stuff is removed". <-- But it seems it only gets removed if you explicitly call status.setComplete() - how else would Spring know which is the last POST? So my question asks "What if you accidentally forget to call session.setComplete()?