# @ModelAttribute method isn't called again in a Portlet Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay, portlet

My question boils down to: How you do get spring mvc to call `@ModelAttribute` after it has already been populated?

To elaborate, I'm messing around with the BookCatalog example from chapter 8 from *Portlets in Action* 
by Ashish Sarin (Which is really good) and I've run into a problem where the method annotated with 
`@ModelAttribute` is only called once even upon successive loads. For instance:

1. BookCatalog Portlet is displayed
2. Click Edit Book1. Book1 is displayed in the edit form
3. Click home
4. Click Edit Book2. Book1 is *still* displayed in the edit form

I've added sysouts to the begining of each method to see what is being called where. The results are as follows:

```
showBooks 
getBook!
initBinder
showEditBookForm
showBooks
initBinder <- Where is getBook!?
showEditBookForm
```

I read somewhere that `@ModelAttribute` methods are called whenever `@ModelAttribute` 
parameters are requested. So I tried adding `@ModelAttribute("book") Book book` to the showEditBookForm but that still doesn't seem to trigger the `@ModelAttribute` method.

I'm using Spring 3.1.3.RELEASE and deploying with maven to Liferay 6.1.1.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

EditBookController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="VIEW")
@SessionAttributes({"book"})
public class EditBookController {

    ...

    @RenderMapping(params="myaction=editBookForm")
    public String showEditBookForm(@ModelAttribute("book") Book book) {
       System.out.println("showEditBookForm");
       return "editBookForm"
    }

    @InitBinder("book")
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
       System.out.println("initBinder");
       binder.registerCustomEditor(Long.class, new LongNumberPropertyEditor());
       binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] {"isbnNumber"});
    }

    @ModelAttribute("book")
    public Book getBook(@RequestParam Long isbnNumber) {
       System.out.println("getBook!");
       return bookService.getBook(isbnNumber);
    }

    ...
}
```

BookController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "VIEW")
public class BookController {
    ...
    @RenderMapping
    public String showBooks(RenderResponse response,SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
       System.out.println("showBooks");
       return "home";
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this line of code:

```
@SessionAttributes({"book"})
public class EditBookController {
```

You're using the "book" attribute as a Session Attribute. This implies that the first time a Request is made to the Portal, the framework will verify an attribute with that name is present in Portlet Session. If it is not, it will call the corresponding `@ModelAttribute` method to generate an instance and put it into Session. But if there's already an attribute in Session with that name, the Controller will use the existing object.

So, the first time you're invoking the Book Catalog Portlet an instance of the Book Attribute is generated and stored in Session. But the second time -as an object is already in Session- the Portlet will use the object generated in the first request. If you want to clear every object stored in Session after a render or action request you just need to call `SessionStatus.setComplete()` to trigger a Session cleanup.

That's what theory and the book said, but there's some buggy behaviour in `SessionStatus.setComplete()` and the [Book Author has some thoghts about it](http://www.google.com.pe/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=manning%20portlet%20in%20action%20buggy&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?threadID=39694&ei=dlO5UKv1FJPi9gSDo4CoBQ&usg=AFQjCNG7_RhYPkbJzDSaIgjZXjY6MCXZxg).

Comment: Hmm... but won't SessionStatus.setComplete() scrap the entire Session? There isn't a more targeted way?

Comment: Or maybe just don't use 'book' as a Session Attribute

Comment: After [reading this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9331400/792789) and then doing some debugging I've found that  SesssionStatus.setComplete() only cleans the current Controller's @SessionAttributes.

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate what I eventually landed on:

```
@RenderMapping(params="myaction=editBookForm")
public String showEditBookForm(
        @ModelAttribute("book") Book book
        , @RequestParam Long isbnNumber
        , SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
        System.out.println("showEditBookForm");

       if(book != null 
          && book.getIsbnNumber() != isbnNumber) {
           sessionStatus.setComplete();
       }

       return "editBookForm";
}
```