# @SessionAttributes and @ResponseBody do not work together

Tags: spring-mvc

I have created a very simple "test" controller that keeps a counter in session to print how many times a request handler is called.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("counter")
public class MyController {

    @ModelAttribute("counter")
    public Counter addCounter(){
        System.out.println("Counter added to model");
        return new Counter();
    }


    @RequestMapping("printCounter")
    @ResponseBody
    public String printCounter(Model model){

        Counter counter = (Counter)model.asMap().get("counter");
        int currVal = counter.getValue();
        System.out.println("Current value: " + currVal);

        counter.increment();


        return "hello-view";
    }

}
```

Every thing works fine, but when I try to use   @ResponseBody on the response  it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been   committed
```

I have found several work around. I know the error happens  because spring has already flushed the response when trying to add the counter to the session. What I do not know is why spring is doing so.

Since the issue has been there for so long I imagine it is done on propose.

Does any body know what is the motivation for implementing it this way?

Why can we store data in the session if the method  is returning body content but we can if it  returns a view name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: every time you access /printCounter the new Counter is set as the addCounter() is executed for every request to this controller. So when int currVal = counter.getValue(); it will always be 0

Comment: Did you try to ask Spring to create the session : @RequestMapping("printCounter") @ResponseBody public String printCounter(Model model, HttpSession session) { ...` ?

Comment: Hello @NeelamMehta, since I @SessionAttributes("counter") the method is called only one per session

Comment: @SergeBallesta What you say will solve the issue. but my understanding  is that it should not be needed. In fact, if I do not use @ ResponseBody it works file.

Comment: @fdm : @ModelAttribute("counter")
    public Counter addCounter(){
        System.out.println("Counter added to model");
        return new Counter();
    }  this method is called every time the controller serves a request So you will always have "Counter added to model
Current value: 0"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@SessionAttribute` is not the best designed concept in SpringFramework (see this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26387605/3545273) for another caveat).

When you forward to a view, Spring has all the time to deal with session attributes before calling the view : nothing has been written to the request at the time the controller method returns. But when you use `@ResponseBody`, the return value of the method is directly written to the response and the response is immediately committed. So it may be too late for Spring to create a session to save the model attributes. Ok, it could have been designed in a way that it would not be necessary. But *as you can always ask for eagerly creating a session* by giving a `HttpSession` parameter to the controller method, I suppose Spring fellows think it is enough.

Comment: Hello Serge. I think this is what really happens, but still I do not understand why they implemented this way. They can first create the session and them write the response. Thanks for your time.